# Get value preceding certain value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['d',5,6],['a',6,6],['index',5,8],['b',3,1],['b',5,6],['index',6,7],
                ['e',2,3],['c',5,6],['index',5,8]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Then `df` is:

```
         A  B  C
  0      d  5  6
  1      a  6  6
  2  index  5  8
  3      b  3  1
  4      b  5  6
  5  index  6  7
  6      e  2  3
  7      c  5  6
  8  index  5  8
```

select the element above (preceding) the element `'index'` . I want to obtain an array as

```
 output=[a,b,c]
```

Comment: question is not very clear. Please clarify ? I do not understand...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, Try using `shift`, then `loc` to find where `'index'` is in column `A`:

```
df.shift().loc[df.A=='index','A'].tolist()

['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a comprehension

```
a = df.A.values
[x for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]) if y == 'index']

['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy.where`:

```
a = df.A.values
a[np.where(a[1:]=='index')].tolist()
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtract `1` from the indices where the value `'index'` occurs:

```
df.loc[df[df['A'] == 'index'].index - 1, 'A'].tolist()
```

Comment: This is assuming `index` is numeric and in order.

Comment: @piRSquared good point (all the other answers were already taken :)